# Backup / Mirror Github repositories

Tags: backup, github

I'd like to periodically create a backup of my github repositories.  Is there a quick way to pull all of them without knowing what the entire list is?

Walter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer I was waiting for.

I decided to give Ruby a try and it is okay.  I like how it is compact, but it isn't pretty looking :(.

This works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "yaml"
require "open-uri"

time = Time.new
backupDirectory = "/storage/backups/github.com/#{time.year}.#{time.month}.#{time.day}"
username = "walterjwhite"

#repositories =
# .map{|r| %Q[#{r[:name]}] }

#FileUtils.mkdir_p #{backupDirectory}

YAML.load(open("http://github.com/api/v2/yaml/repos/show/#{username}"))['repositories'].map{|repository|

    puts "found repository: #{repository[:name]} ... downloading ..."
    #exec
    system "git clone git@github.com:#{username}/#{repository[:name]}.git #{backupDirectory}/#{repository[:name]}"
}
```

Walter

Answer (score 3):

Now that the v2 API used in the accepted answer no longer works, it's time for an update that uses [Github API v3](http://developer.github.com/v3).

You can get the [list of repositories](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/) in JSON format with

```
curl -i https://api.github.com/users/username/repos
```

Watch out for pagination!  By default the results are [paginated to 30 items](http://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination).  If you have more repositories than fit into a single page, you'll get a `Link` HTTP response header with links to the other pages (with rel=next/last/first/prev).  You can also ask for a larger page size (up to 100):

```
curl -i https://api.github.com/users/username/repos?per_page=100
```

A full backup script (assuming you have 100 or fewer repositories) would look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import json
import urllib
import subprocess

username = 'username'  # specify your github username
os.chdir(os.expanduser('~/github'))  # location for your backups, must exist

url = 'https://api.github.com/users/%s/repos?per_page=100' % username
for repo in json.load(urllib.urlopen(url)):
    print "+", repo['full_name']
    if os.path.exists(repo['name']):
        subprocess.call(['git', 'pull'], cwd=repo['name'])
    else:
        subprocess.call(['git', 'clone', repo['git_url']])
```

Comment: I intend to maintain a working version of this script at  https://gist.github.com/4319265

Answer (score 2):

You can get the entire list via GitHub's API:

```
curl http://github.com/api/v2/yaml/repos/show/walterjwhite
```

For example, this simple DOS/Unix shell one-liner:

```
ruby -ryaml -ropen-uri -e "puts YAML.load(open('http://github.com/api/v2/yaml/repos/show/walterjwhite'))['repositories'].map {|r| %Q[* **#{r[:name]}** (#{r[:description]}) is at <#{r[:url]}/>] }"
```

prints (assuming you have Ruby installed):

- **logback** (The reliable, generic, fast and flexible logging framework for Java.) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/logback/
- **Test-Automation** (provides UI Test Automation framework) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/Test-Automation/
- **model.base** (Base Model Project) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.base/
- **project.configuration** (Project Configuration (Jalopy, Checkstyle, etc.)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/project.configuration/
- **model.http** (Http Models / Enties) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.http/
- **model.address** (Address models and entities) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.address/
- **model.geolocation.base** (Geolocation models and entities) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.geolocation.base/
- **model.user** (User models and entities) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.user/
- **model.annotations.current** (Used to inject the current date / user into an entity) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.annotations.current/
- **model.annotations.deidentify** (Used to deidentify PHI fields) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.annotations.deidentify/
- **model.annotations.verify** (Used to verify fields (email address, address, phone number, etc.)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.annotations.verify/
- **model.time** (Time entities) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.time/
- **model.http-security** (Http Security entities) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.http-security/
- **model.restriction.base** (Base Restriction Models) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.restriction.base/
- **model.restriction.time** (Time Restrictions) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.restriction.time/
- **model.restriction.user** (User/Group/Role Restrictions) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.restriction.user/
- **model.web.base** (Base Web Model) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.web.base/
- **model.web.resource** (Web Resource Model Project) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.web.resource/
- **model.web.file** (File model) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.web.file/
- **model.web.content** (Web Content Models) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.web.content/
- **model.deployment** (Deployment models / entities) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.deployment/
- **model.geolocation.tracking** (Geolocation Tracking) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.geolocation.tracking/
- **model.geolocation.device-location** (Device Location models) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.geolocation.device-location/
- **model.defect** (Defect models / entities) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.defect/
- **model.test.error** (Test Errors) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.test.error/
- **model.web.automation.history** (Test History) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.web.automation.history/
- **model.html** (Test Html) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.html/
- **model.test.user** (Test Http) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.test.user/
- **model.web.automation.test** (Test Test entities) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.web.automation.test/
- **model.web.automation.validation** (Test Validation entities) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.web.automation.validation/
- **service.query.base** (Provides framework for automatically injecting queries from an interface definition + annotation) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/service.query.base/
- **service.query.defect** (Provides query service for querying against defects / fixes) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/service.query.defect/
- **service.query.deployment** (Deployment query service) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/service.query.deployment/
- **model.restriction.geolocation** (Geolocation restrictions) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.restriction.geolocation/
- **service.query.address** (Address query servicd) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/service.query.address/
- **service.query.geolocation.device-location** (Device Location Query Service) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/service.query.geolocation.device-location/
- **service.query.geolocation.base** (Geolocation Query Service) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/service.query.geolocation.base/
- **service.query.http** (Http Query Service) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/service.query.http/
- **service.query.http-security** (Http Security query service) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/service.query.http-security/
- **service.query.user** (User Query Service) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/service.query.user/
- **service.query.web.file** (Web File Query Service) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/service.query.web.file/
- **service.query.web.content** (Web Content Query Service) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/service.query.web.content/
- **observer.startup.deployment** (Startup Event Observer (deployment)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/observer.startup.deployment/
- **observer.startup.defect** (Startup Event Observer (defect)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/observer.startup.defect/
- **listener.servlet.request** (Request Servlet Listener) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/listener.servlet.request/
- **util.network** (Network utilities) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/util.network/
- **listener.servlet.geolocation** (Geolocation Servlet Listener) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/listener.servlet.geolocation/
- **listener.persistence.audit** (Audit Persistence Listeners (Hibernate)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/listener.persistence.audit/
- **listener.persistence.current** (Current (User / Date) Persistence Listeners) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/listener.persistence.current/
- **listener.persistence.restriction** (Restriction Persistence Listener (secures entities on load)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/listener.persistence.restriction/
- **service.geolocation** (Geolocation update service) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/service.geolocation/
- **service.notification** (Notification Service) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/service.notification/
- **service.traffic-analysis** (Traffic Analysis Service) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/service.traffic-analysis/
- **servlet.file** (File Servlet) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/servlet.file/
- **util.web.file** (File Utilities) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/util.web.file/
- **servlet.filter.base** (Base Servlet Filters) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/servlet.filter.base/
- **servlet.filter.web.content** (Web Content servlet filter) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/servlet.filter.web.content/
- **servlet.filter.security** (Security servlet filters) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/servlet.filter.security/
- **io.file** (File functions (deprecated)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/io.file/
- **deprecated.listener.postInitialization.libraryLogger** (Library Logger (deprecated)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/deprecated.listener.postInitialization.libraryLogger/
- **deprecated.listener.startup.databaseImporter** (Database Importer (allows multiple import.sql scripts to be run on server start)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/deprecated.listener.startup.databaseImporter/
- **deprecated.listener.startup.scheduler** (Scheduler (enables jobs to be schedule simply with annotations)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/deprecated.listener.startup.scheduler/
- **docbook** (Docbook format (provides docbook configuration for standard formatting)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/docbook/
- **deprecated.model.client** (Client models) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/deprecated.model.client/
- **deprecated.model.virtualhost** (Virtualhost models) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/deprecated.model.virtualhost/
- **util.web.resource** (Web Resource utils (deprecated, use security listeners instead for transparent security of entities)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/util.web.resource/
- **servlet.filter.notification** (Notification servlet filter) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/servlet.filter.notification/
- **spring-core** (base project for spring projects (deprecated)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/spring-core/
- **view.content** (JSF components for content projects (provides the view layer)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/view.content/
- **documentation.server-setup** (Documentation for setting up a server (trying to make a repeatable process and ensure fewer defects and potential vulnerabilities)) is at
  http://github.com/walterjwhite/documentation.server-setup/
- **server.http** (Http Server using JBoss Netty) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/server.http/
- **listener.persistence.deidentify** (Deidentification persistence listener) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/listener.persistence.deidentify/
- **util.http** (Http Utilities) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/util.http/
- **deprecated.service.translate** (Translation Service) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/deprecated.service.translate/
- **html5.example.danforys.mesmerizer** (HTML5 grid example) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/html5.example.danforys.mesmerizer/
- **html5.framework** (HTML5 framework (caching, client renderering, etc.)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/html5.framework/
- **documentation.os.open-solaris** (Open Solaris Documentation) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/documentation.os.open-solaris/
- **documentation.development** (Development Documentation) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/documentation.development/
- **interceptor.exception** (Generic exception interceptor for CDI) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/interceptor.exception/
- **observer.http-security** (Http Security Observer (authentication events)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/observer.http-security/
- **model.preference.base** (Base Preference model project) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.preference.base/
- **model.preference.notification** (Notification Preference Models) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.preference.notification/
- **deprecated.web.base** (Deprecated project (abstract web components)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/deprecated.web.base/
- **model.annotations.ui** (Annotations for automatically rendering Web Action Entities) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.annotations.ui/
- **model.web.action.geolocation** (Geolocation web action models) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.web.action.geolocation/
- **listener.servlet.web.traffic** (Web Traffic Servlet Listener (captures web traffic)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/listener.servlet.web.traffic/
- **model.web.traffic** (Web Traffic models (for capturing HTML5 traffic, can be used for HTML4 as well)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.web.traffic/
- **iterator.sql** (SQL Iterator (for iterating through SQL scripts)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/iterator.sql/
- **model.notification** (Notification Models/Entities) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.notification/
- **model.fmea** (FMEA models (for capturing potential failure mode and effects analysis)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.fmea/
- **service.web.automation.operator** (Operator for web automation project (simulates an application user)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/service.web.automation.operator/
- **deprecated.iterator.web-automation** (Web Automation iterators (page navigation)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/deprecated.iterator.web-automation/
- **deprecated.OS.gentoo.install** (Gentoo Install scripts (deprecated)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/deprecated.OS.gentoo.install/
- **web.action.base** (Base Web Action module) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/web.action.base/
- **web.action.contact.email** (Provides the web action for contacting the web site via email) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/web.action.contact.email/
- **web.action.geolocation** (Provides geolocation web action (type in an ip address, get back a geolocation)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/web.action.geolocation/
- **web.action.search** (Search web action (ability to search through all entities provided the user has permission)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/web.action.search/
- **web.action.user** (User web actions (for managing users)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/web.action.user/
- **web.service.geolocation** (Geolocation web service) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/web.service.geolocation/
- **service.query.web.resource** (Web Resource query service) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/service.query.web.resource/
- **model.web.action.contact.email** (Email backing the Contact action) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.web.action.contact.email/
- **interceptor.web** (intercepts web action/service methods for auditing purposes) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/interceptor.web/
- **prettyfaces.extension.sitemap** (Prettyfaces sitemap extension (automatically generates a sitemap and publishes it to google, yahoo, msn, etc.)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/prettyfaces.extension.sitemap/
- **prettyfaces-tests** (Some PrettyFaces test webapps) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/prettyfaces-tests/
- **scheduler.quartz** (Quartz Job Scheduler manager (initializes a quartz job scheduler ...)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/scheduler.quartz/
- **observer.rFactor** (rFactor event observers (for managing an rFactor server)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/observer.rFactor/
- **observer.event-planner** (Event Planner observers) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/observer.event-planner/
- **web.action.news** (News web action components) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/web.action.news/
- **web.action.rFactor** (rFactor web actions (managing rFactor servers, configurations, races, etc.)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/web.action.rFactor/
- **web.action.contact.chat** (Chat web action components) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/web.action.contact.chat/
- **service.automation.web.search.job** (Job Search Web Automation Service) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/service.automation.web.search.job/
- **deprecated.service.analytics** (analytics service (deprecated, use an actual reporting package instead)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/deprecated.service.analytics/
- **service.backup** (Backup Service (backs up a database, log files, etc.)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/service.backup/
- **model.web.action.bookmark** (bookmark web action models) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.web.action.bookmark/
- **model.web.action.search** (search models) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.web.action.search/
- **model.web.action.decision** (Decisicion models (for capturing decisions and outcomes, useful for design decisions, and of course endless possibilities)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.web.action.decision/
- **model.weather** (weather models) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.weather/
- **model.recipe** (recipe models) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.recipe/
- **model.web.action.search.job** (Job Search web action models) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.web.action.search.job/
- **model.web.action.task** (Task web action models) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.web.action.task/
- **model.travel** (Travel Models) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.travel/
- **model.events** (Events model) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.events/
- **model.lodging** (Lodging model) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.lodging/
- **model.business.billing** (Billing Business Models (for capturing billing information)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.business.billing/
- **model.business.business** (Business Models (for capturing billing information)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.business.business/
- **model.business.service** (Service Business Models (for capturing services provided)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.business.service/
- **model.business.restaurant** (Restaurant Business Models (for capturing billing information)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.business.restaurant/
- **model.news** (News models) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.news/
- **model.project** (Project models (for tracking projects, work, tasks, etc.)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.project/
- **model.meal** (Meal models) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.meal/
- **model.gaming.rFactor** (rFactor game models) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.gaming.rFactor/
- **model.question-and-answer** (Question and Answer models) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.question-and-answer/
- **model.feedback** (Feedback models) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.feedback/
- **linuxtag2010_javaEE6** (Example code of Java EE 6 tutorial at Linuxtag 2010.) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/linuxtag2010_javaEE6/
- **deprecated.navigation.web.automation** (Navigation Web automation module) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/deprecated.navigation.web.automation/
- **model.career** (Career models / entities) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.career/
- **model.clothing** (Clothing models / entities) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/model.clothing/
- **deprecated.model.crawler** (deprecated, these projects will be split up (reference purposes only)) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/deprecated.model.crawler/
- **resume** (My Resume) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/resume/
- **business-cards** (Business Cards) is at http://github.com/walterjwhite/business-cards/

Comment: Hmm, okay, what I will need to do is create a list, iterate through it, and then download the repository.  That is another script.